# Multithreading issues on Android

Tags: android, multithreading, algorithm, image-processing, android-bitmap

I'm working on multithreading image processing on Android and I'm facing an issue I can't clarify.

On some phones, even old ones, I get some decent timings and on more recents ones, unacceptable ones.

[image]

Some code :

```
public class ShiftEffectManager implements ShiftRunnable.OnShiftRunCompleteListener {

    ...

    public ShiftEffectManager(OnEffectAppliedListener listener, Bitmap source) {
        mService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_THREADS);

        ...
    }

    public void execute() {

        ...

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
            mService.submit(new ShiftRunnable(this, getFraction(mSource, start, step), start, offsets));
        }
    }

    private Bitmap getFraction(Bitmap source, int start, int step) {
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, start, source.getWidth(), step);
    }

    @UiThread
    private void assembleBitmap() {
        ...
        ((Activity) mListener).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mListener.onEffectApplied(output);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onShiftRunComplete(ShiftFractionPayload payload) {
        mPayloads.add(payload);
        mTaskCount++;

        if (mTaskCount == MAX_THREADS) {
            assembleBitmap();
        }
    }
}
```

`ShiftRunnable` is parsing a 1920 * (1080 / MAX_THREADS) and shifting red and blue channels on a given offset. Thus, getPixels() and setPixels() several times per pass.

Is it a device related issue, an OS one (since both 'faulty' devices are in 6.x) ?

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I'm not a expert, but might be a memory related cause. Every change you're creating a new bitmap that usually takes a big amount of memory.

Comment: Also looks like threads will not operate on the same part of bitmap, so maybe you don't need multiple copies of it?

Comment: I provide each thread only a fraction of source bitmap. But wouldn't I suffer from this supposed memory issue on the Wiko Darkmoon ?

Comment: After some extensive testing on a 7.x phone and on API 17 emu and API 25 emu, it seems that post-Marshmallow multithreading, at least the way I do it, isn't very OS friendly.

Comment: `post-Marshmallow multithreading, at least the way I do it`. Probably. I do multi threaded image resizing and it also fast on 7.1.1.

Comment: How do you do it ?

Comment: Can you turn strict mode and see if something is running long on UI thread?

Comment: BTW, you can also profile it and see more information where time is going

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't a multithreading issue after all...

Calling getPixel(x, y) and setPixel(x, y) multiple times per pass was slowing down the execution. 
But, for an unknown reason, it was way worse on post Marshmallow devices / emulators.

Using getPixels() / setPixels() from/in an `int[width * height]` array is now tremendously more efficient. 
We are now speaking in milliseconds, not seconds.